# Is there a good reason to use `sort` with `index.return = TRUE` instead of `order`?

Tags: r, sorting

`sort` has the argument `index.return` which is by default `FALSE`. If you set it to `TRUE` you get the ordering index... basically the same as when you use `order`.

**My question**
Are there cases where it makes sense to use `sort` with `index.return = TRUE` instead of `order`?

Comment: FWIW `sort` calls this `x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)]` for non-integer inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`order` simply gives the indexes, instead `sort` gives also the values (and with  `index.return=T` a `list`):

```
x <- runif(10, 0, 100)
order(x)
# [1]  2  7  1  9  6  5  8 10  4  3
sort(x, index.return=T)
# $`x`
# [1] 0.08140348 0.18272011 0.23575252 0.51493537 0.64281259 0.92121388 0.93759670 0.96221375 0.97646916 0.97863369
# 
# $ix
# [1]  2  7  1  9  6  5  8 10  4  3
```

It seems that `order` is a little faster with big numbers (longer vector size):

```
x <- runif(10000000, 0, 100)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sort = {sort(x, index.return=T)},
  order = {x[order(x)]},
  times = 100
)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# sort 63.48221 67.79530 78.33724 70.74215 74.10109 173.1129   100
# order 56.46055 57.18649 60.88239 58.29462 62.13086 155.5481   100
```

So probably you should pick sort with `index.return = TRUE` only if you need a `list` object to be returned. I can't find an example where `sort` is better than the other.

Comment: To clarify, by "big numbers" you mean `order` is faster with sorting vectors with lots of numbers, not numbers that are large in magnitude, right?

Comment: Yes I meant longer vector size. I checked at it seems that even with numbers of bigger magniture is still a little faster. It doesn't change much if you use `runif(10000000, 0, 100)` or `runif(10000000, 0, 10000)`.

Comment: Sometimes sort(x,method-"quick",...) is faster so you could test also with this arguments. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions are based on RLave's answer.

You could use the argument `method`, `sort(x,method="quick",index.return=TRUE)`, and the function might be a little faster than the default. Also if you want a faster (for large vectors) alternative method of this, you can use this function:

```
sort_order <- function(x){
    indices <- order(x) #you can choose a method also but leave default.
    list("x"=x[indices],"ix"=indices)
}
```

Here are some benchmarks.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
     sort=s<-sort(x,index.return=T),
     "quick sort"=sq<-sort(x,method="quick",index.return=T),
     "order sort"=so<-sort_order(x),times = 10
     times=10
)

Unit: seconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
         sort 1.493714 1.662791 1.737854 1.708502 1.887993 1.960912    10
   quick sort 1.366938 1.374874 1.451778 1.444342 1.480122 1.668693    10
   order sort 1.181974 1.344398 1.359209 1.369108 1.424569 1.461862    10

all.equal(so,sq)
[1] TRUE
all.equal(s,so)
[1] TRUE
```